# If $au + bv + cw = 0$ with $a+b + c = 0$ then $u,v,w$ are collinear

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, geometry

If $u,v,w \in \mathbb R^3$ such that for some $a,b,c$ real numbers with $a+b+c = 0$ we have $au + bv + cw = 0$, then why are $u,v,w$ collinear points?

i substituted $a = -b-c$ and tried other things but i still don't see why they are collinear

thanks for help.

Edit: suppose that one of $a,b,c$ is non-zero

Comment: They are coplanar but I don't think they have to be collinear. For example take $a=b=1,c=-2$, and $u = (2,0,0), v = (0,2,0), w=(1,1,0)$.

Comment: @chemicaholic i wanted to say "collinear points"

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut edited to avoid that

Comment: Ok, however $a+b=0$ with $a\neq 0$ and $b\neq 0$, and $c=0$ won't help much: in that case, $u,v$ are collinear, and you know nothing about $w$. However, you know for sure $u,v,w$ are co**planar**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may assume $a,b,c\neq 0$ (otherwise this is easy, since two points coincide). By multiplying given inequality by $-1$ if necessary we can assume two of $a,b,c$ are positive, say $a,b$ are. Then we can write $au+bv=(a+b)w$, or $\frac{a}{a+b}u+\frac{b}{a+b}v=w$. Hence $w$ is a convex combination of $u,v$, so it lies on the interval with endpoints $u,v$. Hence, $u,v,w$ lie on a line.

Comment: brilliant. thanks

Answer (score 0):

First says that (u,v,w) lies on a plane normal to (a,b,c). The second says that the normal (a,b,c) lies in the plane perpendicular to (1,1,1). So all you know at this point is that (u,v,w) lies on a plane (and you know a little about how the plane can be oriented).

What would make them collinear is if you required ua+vb+wc=0 for ALL (a,b,c). In that case, (u,v,w) has to lie on the line along (1,1,1).